# why does git pick up changes that have not been merged?

Tags: git, bitbucket

in my BranchA:

```
git add -u
git commit -m "fix weird issue"
git push origin origin/BranchA
```

In bitbucket:
Create new branch, BranchB from master

In command prompt:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b origin/BranchB
git pull -u origin origin/BranchB
//Updating 3 files, fast forward...
git status
// everything is clean
```

3 files show up locally even though BranchA has not been merged to master. Why?

Comment: Assuming you were on `BranchA` and didn't switch branches, `git pull -u origin origin/BranchB` fetched `origin/BranchB` from the `origin` remote and merged that branch into your current branch, `BranchA`. Since `BranchB` and `master` point to the same commit, you now have "`master` stuff" into your `BranchA`. Did you mean to do that? Also, any reason why you're using the `-u` flag in `git pull`?

Comment: @Jubobs when I did a checkout -b origin/BranchB I switched to BranchB. I did a git pull -u to track the remote for the pull/push, so you can just write `git pull`

Answer (score 0):

A better sequence would be:

```
git add -u
git commit -m "fix weird issue"
git push -u origin branchA

git fetch
git checkout -b branchB origin/branchB
```

No need for the final pull

Comment: But why would the final pull fetch the unmerged changed from BranchA, is basically my question.

Comment: @doorfly that is why I don't do the final pull: I don't want to merge anything, just start a local branch based on the new and fetched branchB from origin.

Comment: so the pull actually did a merge including branch commits to B from master? Even though the changes from A has not yet been merged to master?

Comment: @doorfly a pull is a fetch plus a merge. Here you don't need pull at all, since you already did a fetch.

Comment: A merge from master including commits from other branches? That would be the only explanation of why commits in BranchA got into BranchB.

Comment: @doorfly a merge from whatever branch you are pulling onto your current local branch. Again, in your case, you don't need to do any merge, just to start a branch. So no pull needed.

Comment: Okay forget the issue of whether the pull is necessary for a moment. Why does the pull get the changes from BranchA when BranchB a branch off of master?

Comment: @doorfly because your current branch, when you did the pull, must have been branchA

Comment: That's a possibility, but I am pretty sure `git checkout -b origin/BranchB`should have put me into BranchB. I will check it out and try to reproduce this later.